# xslt xml table records pagination

Tags: xml, xslt

I a very simple xml table with lots of lines which need a paged display. I know this question's been asked before (one way or the other), but it never was given a real, good solution.

And just for the record, I think one of the real instance where xslt is coming into very handy is for xslt pagination for which - I don't know the reason - wasn't really explained thoroughly anywhere over the web. Only incomplete, not working or some lapidary examples were given. Complete unsatisfactory nor useful.

That's why I just hit in here again over this matter.
I'll start out with some rather simple .xml example which somehow fits that .xsl paging example i'll present further down here.

.xml sample:

```
<group>
 <item> 01 </item>
 <item> 02 </item>
 <item> 03 </item>
 <item> 04 </item>
 <item> 05 </item>
 <item> 06 </item>
 <item> 07 </item>
 <item> 08 </item>
 <item> 09 </item>
 <item> 10 </item>
 <item> 11 </item>
 <item> 12 </item>
 <item> 13 </item>
 <item> 14 </item>
 <item> 15 </item>
 <item> 16 </item>
 <item> 17 </item>
 <item> 18 </item>
 <item> 19 </item>
 <item> 20 </item>
 <item> 21 </item>
 <item> 22 </item>
 <item> 23 </item>
 <item> 24 </item>
 <item> 25 </item>
 <item> 26 </item>
</group>
```

and corresponding .xsl (taken from some site, but parts truncated for brevity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
 <xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:variable name="recordsPerPage" select="5"/>
 <xsl:variable name="pageNumber">
  <xsl:choose>
  <!-- first page -->
  <xsl:when test="$currentPage &lt;= 0 or $currentPage = '' or $currentPage = 'NaN'">0</xsl:when>
   <!-- what was passed in -->
  <xsl:otherwise>
  <xsl:value-of select="$currentPage"/>
 </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="numberOfRecords" select="count(/group/item)"/>
<!-- The fun starts here --> 
<ul class="listing self-clear">
 <xsl:for-each select="//item">
  <xsl:if test="position() &gt; $recordsPerPage * number($pageNumber) and position() &lt;= number($recordsPerPage * number($pageNumber) + $recordsPerPage )">
  <li>
   <xsl:attribute name="class">
     <xsl:if test="position() = $recordsPerPage * (number($pageNumber) + 1)">last</xsl:if>
     </xsl:attribute>
      <h4> <xsl:value-of select="text()"/> </h4>
  </li>
 </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
<xsl:call-template name="pagination">
<xsl:with-param name="pageNumber" select="$pageNumber"/>
<xsl:with-param name="recordsPerPage" select="$recordsPerPage"/>
<xsl:with-param name="numberOfRecords" select="$numberOfRecords"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="pagination">
  <xsl:param name="pageNumber"/>
  <xsl:param name="recordsPerPage"/>
  <xsl:param name="numberOfRecords"/>
<div class="pagination">
<div class="wrapper">
 <xsl:if test="(($pageNumber +1) * $recordsPerPage) &lt; ($numberOfRecords)">
  <a href="?page={$pageNumber + 1}" class="next">Next</a>
 </xsl:if>
 <span class="page-nos">Page </span>
  <xsl:if test="$pageNumber &gt; 0">
   <a href="?page={$pageNumber - 1}" class="prev">Prev</a>
  </xsl:if>
 </div>
</div>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This style is not actually working. as it "partially" does.
The whole process is incomplete and wrongfully displayed as such.

I need this solution working:

first prev page x / y next last

Down here I just put some working fiddle example for one to understands exactly what I (truly) mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/MrcaS48/2e9kq3v0/

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you mean by "pagination". Please edit your question and show the expected output of processing the input example.

Comment: You've told us a lot about why you are asking the question, and you've shown us partial code that you say doesn't work, but you haven't actually stated what the problem is. Just saying it's "pagination" isn't enough. You haven't even said whether you are producing a fixed or variable number of records per page.

Comment: I'd like to see those XSLT "lapidary examples."

Comment: Noticed that you people failed getting my point. I just put up that working fiddle for showing my expected result ! Through that, one could precisely check how I really need that .xml to be switched through pages !
What I mean by that is: need to display (by xslt transform) that xml file using xslt generated pages, **one page at a time** and that pass over next/prev page should be made with help of those <a> links down at the viewport's bottom (not be confused with all html passing pages). Those links helps navigating back and forth over those pages (which are grouped in 3,4,5 records).

Comment: *"Noticed that you people failed getting my point."* Right. It's your point and our failure.

Comment: No, by no means I didn't meant to offend you !
 Thing is, in here I'm drastically limited for the sentence's numbers of characters so I only wanted to make my comments as brief as possible.
 I'm struggling for this "solution" for weeks even months, and that's why I kept pop up here with this silly issue of mine.
 Really i'm terrible sorry if I did say something unpleasant or .. 
 I repeat, only tried making myself clear for some help, eventually.
 Thank you, and my apologies again !!

Comment: I am not offended. I just don't have a clue what your question is. But at this point it doesn't matter much because I don't intend to spend any more time on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am guessing (!) correctly, you want to divide the items into equal-sized groups. This can be achieved rather simply doing:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:variable name="groupSize" select="5" />

<xsl:template match="/group">
    <html>
        <body>
            <!-- select  every first item in a group -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item[position() mod $groupSize = 1]" />
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <div id="set{position()}">
        <ul>
            <!-- list self and following siblings within this group -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::item[position() &lt; $groupSize]" mode="item" />        
        </ul>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item" mode="item">
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

**Result**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="set1">
      <ul>
        <li> 01 </li>
        <li> 02 </li>
        <li> 03 </li>
        <li> 04 </li>
        <li> 05 </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="set2">
      <ul>
        <li> 06 </li>
        <li> 07 </li>
        <li> 08 </li>
        <li> 09 </li>
        <li> 10 </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="set3">
      <ul>
        <li> 11 </li>
        <li> 12 </li>
        <li> 13 </li>
        <li> 14 </li>
        <li> 15 </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="set4">
      <ul>
        <li> 16 </li>
        <li> 17 </li>
        <li> 18 </li>
        <li> 19 </li>
        <li> 20 </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="set5">
      <ul>
        <li> 21 </li>
        <li> 22 </li>
        <li> 23 </li>
        <li> 24 </li>
        <li> 25 </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="set6">
      <ul>
        <li> 26 </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: On brief, I just need make working that .xsl previously presented through that fiddle example's guide from here:
   https://jsfiddle.net/MrcaS48/2e9kq3v0/
for displaying fixed (say 5 items / page) paged records **one of a time**, and **not** by _bulked hidden displaying them (all at once hidden) and eventually make them visible_ as one advances through navigation links.
 Does it makes sense clear enough ?

Comment: Hi again, Ok, I think this is half way working my way.
 Anyway, I need to display only 5 nodes at a time, based on some parameter passed in which is the page number. I'll name it as
  param name = "pagnmbr"

 And, first time if this $pagnmbr is 1, that xslt will display:
   01  02  03  04  05 
  Else, if it's 2, it wil display:
    06 07 08 09 10
 And if same parameter become 3, the display will be :
    11 12 13 14 15
 And so on.
 See, this kind of functionality I'm in very need of making.
 Please you guys help me with it !!!
  Thank you very much in advance

Comment: My stylesheet already has a variable named  `groupSize` for this. All you need to do is change it to a parameter (and optionally rename it).

Comment: no, it's not about "groupSize", but  for some PAGE.
"groupSize" is about how many records to display over one single page.
But I need another parameter, say pagNumber which tells on which page one is.
 Example :
 
page 1:
 01  02  03  04  05
page 2:
 06  07  08  09  10
page 3:
 11  12  13  14  15
page 4:
16  17  18  19  20

Displaying ONE bunch of records(5) AT A TIME, not all of them at once!!
 I mean, if I give $pagNumber = 2, it will read:
      06  07  08  09  10 
or if I give $pagNumber = 4, it will pop up :
     16  17  18  19  20
 and so on.
 
Did you get this now ?

Comment: @ michael.hor257k: you see, one have to apply just ONCE that template which matches /group. And this should be related to that pagNmber parameter.

 If $pagNmber =1 

 display starting from 01 ... 02  03 ...

 if $pagNmber = 2
   
 display starting from 06 ... 07   08 ..

 if $pagNmber = 3
  
 display starting from 11 ... 12   13 ..

That template should apply just once, and not all the time following that position() which iterates through the whole node-set !
 I think better suited would be call-template or something ...

 Please, please help me with this .. 
 thanks alot !!

Comment: Okay, I have answered this at your new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344523/xslt-showing-a-group-of-n-xml-nodes-one-at-a-time/56347378#56347378